# What is the cmd.exe command to determine the last mounted drive letter on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, windows-11, drive-letter

I'm trying to be able to determine on the command line (so that I can do it from my scripting language) the drive letter for the **last mounted drive** on Windows 11.

Up until recently, I have used the command `wmic logicaldisk get name` and then extracted the drive letter in the bottom/end of the list. However, I have discovered that this **does not necessarily correspond to the last mounted drive**!

For months, it seemed like it did, but it does not. At least not on Windows 11. I can't tell if it was just working out of sheer luck on Windows 10, or if Microsoft actually changed how this command returns data in Windows 11. Either way, it can no longer be relied upon to put the last mounted in the very end/bottom. So I need some other command to do the same.

**Important**: I have verified that the age-old Windows 10 (and possibly earlier) bug which caused any Powershell command run from `cmd.exe` to mess up the terminal visually has not been fixed in Windows 11, so **I unfortunately cannot use anything that requires calling Powershell**. Please do not suggest Powershell commands. I also cannot drop `cmd.exe` entirely in favour of either `Powershell` or `Windows Terminal` due to the *extreme* slowness and resource (CPU/RAM) usage of these terminals compared to the infinitely faster and leaner `cmd.exe`. It really does make such a critical difference, at least in all my extensive testing.

Comment: Hello, what kind of Windows 10/11 bug are you talking about? I'm using PowerShell within cmd decently often and never noticed anything like that. This is a really weird reason to stay using outdated technology.

Comment: @Destroy666 It's not weird to not use something which breaks the terminal visually.

Comment: Visually in what way?

Comment: Not to disagree @Destroy666 but here in Microsoft we still have many scripts that rely on cmd.exe and wmic.  Deprecated doesn't mean "don't use".  I respect you and I 100% agree that powershell is a superior technology in every way but for instance, we have headless azure servers that don't have powershell on them and this would be the only option.  My problem with the post is perhaps the OP needs to think of a better way of doing things using what they have.

Comment: The problem itself seems like a messy solution.  Who mapped the drives in the first place?  Could it be recorded then?  Is cmd.exe actually needed to traverse the mapped drive because 99% of everything supports UNC paths.  If you give us a better understanding of what you are actually trying to solve, the people here can *probably* help you come up with a better solution.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Drive letters always change around, so they can never be relied on. That's why I use drive labels and construct paths from those. There is nothing strange about what I'm doing whatsoever. What is unclear?

Comment: I didn't say that it was strange.  I have no context.  Nothing is unclear except the purpose of needing the drive letter in the first place.  Understanding the ultimate goal and the scenario might help us help you better.  I understand that you might not be able to or be reluctant to share.  Many of us are Sr. Engineers and *might* be able to think of a better way to solve the problem.  I am only trying to help.

Comment: My system needs to be able to detect new devices to deal with them. I don't understand why you are asking irrelevant questions. I have made an insane, ugly hack which compares the two outputs of that command now to determine the most likely latest inserted drive. It's impossible to get help with the simplest thing...

Comment: `wevtutil qe system "/q:*[System [(EventID=98)][Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Ntfs']]]" /f:text /c:1 /rd:true | find "Volume"` could give you the last mounted volume, you might have to join on the output of "mountvol" or some other lookup to get the drive letter.